# How to pass down Redux store in React Native Router Flux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-router, react-native-router-flux

i've encountered a sligthly more difficult problem than i can handle myself.

Problem:
I want to pass down the redux store as a prop to the login scene, but since the navigator is not a react component and its just a prop in an element which is using connect()...well it's better if i show you some pictures:

[reduxrouter_element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcWFP.png)

[reduxrouter_connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHLPz.png)

[navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxqSl.png)

What should i do?

Thank you for the answers in advance :)

edit.:

I've just simply imported store, and it worked...guess this was some kind of black magic...

Comment: Rather than posting images of code, it's received practice (and far more clear) to post code blocks. To do so, edit your question, paste in the code, highlight the text that needs to be properly formatted, and click the `{}` in the options that you see above the text input field. You'll receive more responses this way.

Comment: Can you describe what your end use case is? Are you simply wanting to access your redux store in the `LoginScene` component?

Comment: Nevermind, i've already solved the problem :)

Comment: In that case, it’s helpful if you can post it as an answer to your own question so others can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** 
I've just simply imported store, and it worked...guess this was some kind of black magic